# How to copy a value from two separate HTML ids?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a feeling this is an incredibly simple operation. I could just use some steer on what exactly I am doing wrong here.

I just need a simple program to take the content from `<span id "text"`> and copy this into `<div id="text2">`.

```js
 function getValue() {
   var text = document.getElementById("text");
   document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = text;
 };

 getValue;
```

```html
<span id="text"> Hi there </span>
<div id="text2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are not calling function properly.

```
getValue();
```

instead of

```
getValue;
```

Comment: this answer is not complete, there is also an error in the function itself (he's assigning a `node` into `innerHTML`)

Comment: cheers guys, i got it. 2 very amateur errors in my code! All working now! thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
function getValue(){
    document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
}

getValue();
```

This code should be in a onload function or in the body tag.

Answer (score -1):

try following:

```
function getValue()
{
    var text=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = text;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
try this jQuery code...

function getValue(){
   $("#text2").text($("#text").text());
}

this works for me...
```